# What's the difference between Boierplates, Frameworks, and Grid Systems?

Tags: css

So I've seen answers to a few similar questions, but none of them are terribly useful to me. I'd like to have a definitive definition of what each is. By the way, for examples of what I mean by each type, I take Bootstrap to be an example of a framework, I take Unsemantic.gs as a Grid System, and, to be honest, have no idea what example I could use for Boilerplates.

I hope someone here can explain the real difference to me in clear and succinct words.

Comment: My idea of a boilerplate is the minimum code to allow it to run.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your tag your are possibly looking for a grid.

A framework is in general a combination of methods of different subtopics of a topic. For instance Rails or Symphony are web frameworks that cover under the topic "web" the subtopics sessions handling, database interfaces, caching, request handling based on type (JSON/XML/HTML). 
In the frontend area Angular or jQuery are frameworks that provide methods of abstraction of subtopics.

In jQuery you do `$.get(...)` instead of `new XMLHttpRequest() ...` - Requests to server

A boilerplate is something you can use for your project to start with. The HTML5 Boilerplate is a really good example. You don't have to worry about the favicons or the Doctypes or the styles and their structure or the device density. Just use it and start developing the web page. It works in the most browsers.
Another example for boilerplates/starting-points are yeoman generators.

Grid systems are a kind of a framework in the CSS area. A grid combines "methods" of CSS, like `display: block` or `width: 960px` to form a table like structure, which can be easily accessed by classes. You got multiple columns on your webpage by using HTML containers and from the grid defined CSS classes. Mostly they cover multiple dimensions of webpages, known as Responsive Design or Adaptive Design.